# How to communicate between 2 different android app on 2 different device (android)?

Tags: android, android-intent

just want to know is there any methods to allow 2 different apps to communicate. Both of the apps are installed on different devices as well. I had gone throught quite a lot of research, but seem that **INTENT, BROADCAST RECEIVER** failed to meet my scenario. **INTENT, BROADCAST RECEIVER** can be work if both of the apps installed on the same device.

Comment: What kind of communication do you want to achieve?

Comment: sending json in string.

Comment: In one local network?

Comment: Should be like sending data via api. So, should be public network.

Comment: In order to perform peer to peer communication you need to utilize the phone's hardware. you may utilize bluetooth, hotspot or NFC to establish a connection between the devices and perform communication throught this network.

Comment: @ganjaam so what u meant is need to use bluetooth, NFC to enable it allow exchange data? If use Socket or more advanced AIDL, is it possible to achieve the result that I wanted ?

Comment: @LiewSyetChau yes. And in best case scenerio you won't even need to write too complicated codes.

Answer (score 0):

Here i can say you can use to make your things work :-

Sockets are typically used to accomplish this between Android devices (or between any peer devices).

When two devices desire to interact, you configure one or both of them to "listen" for connections on a socket and accept a connection from the other when that happens (or you can have a dedicated client and server and the client always initiates the connections).

You can exchange messages after the link has been made.

Android client server socket applications come in a variety of forms, but one that I found handy was:

[Example of Android Server/Client using Socket on the client side](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2014/02/android-sercerclient-example-client.html) (and its companion server side blog article - link included in the client blog)
It should be noted that you might need to add your own "protocol" on top of this. For instance, if you are sending a file that is unknown in length without a special "end" character, you might want to add a byte (or several bytes to represent an int, long, etc.) at the beginning to indicate the length of the transmission so the receiving side can tell when it has received everything (or that it has not received everything in case of an error).

connecting via networks (such as most 3G/4G) that forbid inbound connections

Even though there is nothing theoretically blocking sockets from functioning in these situations, many mobile operators will not permit inbound socket connections in practise. You would also need to determine the mobile's public IP address, which is doable but adds complexity. Whether your solution will only ever operate on a single operator's network, you can test it out to see if it works; but, if it doesn't, you could discover that using a server in the "middle" is preferable and easier: Devices A and B establish connections with servers Device A "discovers" device B after requesting the addresses of connected devices from the server. Device A sends device B a message.
Actually, it indicates that the messages should be forwarded to device B while sending them to the server. Device B is informed by the server that a message is available for it (using some sort of message notification like Google Cloud Messaging for example, or simply by the devices polling regularly to see if they have any messages). Device B accesses the server and downloads the messages. The aforementioned will function on pretty much any network that permits internet connectivity. It does have the drawback of having a server, but for the majority of mobile networks, it is probably a necessary approach.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. May I ask if want to apply socket connection, both sender and receiver also need to apply code changes right in order to send, listen, receive request?

Comment: Yes you need to create server and client changes in accordance to provide and receive.

Answer (score 0):

You make one app a server using ServerSocket.

You make the other app a client using a Socket.

With both devices in the same network the client can connect to the server knowing its local ip.

After connection established they can communicate.